# Getting the following error when doing an NPM install (NJS-054)

Tags: node.js, npm-install, node-oracledb

While trying npm install I get NJS-054 error which is related to the oracledb client. However, the code works just fine when on the local machine. Could anyone help me with the error?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your machine can't find GitHub host.
Map GitHub IP to github.com at the hosts file:

hosts file location on Windows:  `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

```
140.82.118.4 github.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Installing node-oracledb 4 no longer needs GitHub access so installing will be easier.

Regardless of the install problems, version 2.3 is very old so you should consider upgrading. You may need a new Node.js release: 8.16, 10.6, 12 or later.